# Scaling out GAE when memory utilization exceeds limit

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using GAE for heavy tasks with high memory needs. And I got the following error:

```
Exceeded soft memory limit of 512 MB with 561 MB 
after servicing 3 requests total. 
Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

As the tasks are expensive, I assume that two applications can work within one instance. But it does not work for three applications:

```
While handling this request, 
the process that handled this request was found to be using 
too much memory and was terminated. 
This is likely to cause a new process to be used 
for the next request to your application. 
If you see this message frequently, 
you may have a memory leak in your application or may be 
using an instance with insufficient memory.
Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

My current settings:

```
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: B4
basic_scaling:
max_instances: 10
idle_timeout: 1m
```

I also tried with these settings:

```
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.5
  max_instances: 10
```

The failure of executing the task is "**Exceeded soft memory limit**".
So, to solve this error, I think the scale out should be done based on the "memory utilization" rather than "cpu utilization".

How can scaling out be done when the memory utilization exceeds the limit?

Answer (score 2):

The decisions of the dynamic instance scheduler are not based on instance memory usage. From [Scaling dynamic instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_dynamic_instances):

> The App Engine scheduler decides whether to serve each new request
>   with an existing instance (either one that is idle or accepts
>   concurrent requests), put the request in a pending request queue, or
>   start a new instance for that request. The decision takes into account
>   the number of available instances, how quickly your application has
>   been serving requests (its latency), and how long it takes to start a
>   new instance.

The error messages you received all show a very low number of requests being handled before the error happens, which indicates that the memory starvation is very strong.

What isn't clear is if the high memory usage comes from a single request or if it is related to multiple concurrent requests - i.e. requests hitting an instance at the same time (or too close to each-other for the memory freeing mechanism, if any, to keep up). But that can be experimentally determined.

If multiple concurrent incoming requests is what drives the instance memory usage over the threshold you can try to deal with it by controlling the `target_throughput_utilization` and/or `max_concurrent_requests` knobs:

> [Target Throughput Utilization](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#automatic_scaling_target_throughput_utilization)
>
> Sets the throughput threshold for the number of concurrent requests
>   after which more instances will be started to handle traffic.
>
> [Max Concurrent Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#max_concurrent_requests)
>
> Sets the max concurrent requests an instance can accept before the
>   scheduler spawns a new instance.

If the memory limit is being hit even without the instance handling multiple requests simultaneously (or if you would like to be able to serve more instances concurrently - typically to reduce costs) the only way you can address it is by using [instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) with more memory. The `F4` and `B4` classes you tried both have 512M, try `F4_1G`/`B4_1G`, both of which have 1G.

Comment: ` > What isn't clear is if the high memory usage comes from a single request or if it is related to multiple concurrent requests high memory usage comes from single request`

 One http request launch HEADLESS CHRONE by puppeteer and works 1 hour. 
And after one hour, the response will be sent if multiple request has come to one instance, that instance cannot handle its task, so it is better to launch another instance.

Comment: Then just set `max_concurrent_requests` to 1

Comment: max_concurrent_requests　is available only for Automatic scaling but for the purpose to keep instance running, it must be Basic Scaling with long idle_timeout. However Basic Scaling does not have parameter to adjust scale out timing. How can I add new instance with Basic Scaling?

Comment: You're right. Not much you can do except keeping track of the request internally and reject additional requests when one is already in processing. But then you can't really scale dynamically, you may need to switch to manual scaling and build  a separate "dispatcher" service tracking external requests, bringing instances up and down as needed and passing them the external requests to handle.

Comment: Can you elaborate ' > keeping track of the request internally and reject additional requests when one is already in processing.'

Comment: You just need to persist across requests a flag saying if a certain instance is processing a request or not. Donno if standard env nodejs offers an instance global context - that'd be easiest (current instance). If not you'd have to use something like datastore or memcache, combining the flag with the GAE_INSTANCE [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables) to get an instance-flag map Check the flag at the beginning or a requets processing, bail if flag is set. Otherwise set it, processs the request and then clear the flag.

Comment: How about " reject additional requests"?  I have returned `res.sendStatus(503).end();` for test, but it does not create new instance.

Comment: That's what I mean by "you can't really scale dynamically". But at least the instance didn't die as it used to.